# How to tell when a posix thread has terminated

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working on a compiler for fun. I'd like to add some native support for threading. Nothing major, just make-thread, thread-start, thread-kill, and thread-join. The compiler works by taking the source code, compiling it down to LLVM, and combining that LLVM with a C++ header file, which is also compiled to LLVM. The C++ file contains the code for any primitives operations (i.e. all this threading stuff I want to do).

My idea is to have a constant thread pool (96 threads), and have make-thread return an index in that thread pool of a thread that is not currently being used. Then, instead of references to threads, all the other thread operations will just take the index of a thread in the pool.

The issue I'm running into, and can't seem to think a way around, is how to know when a thread is usable again. i.e. I set thread 1 on its journey, and thread 1 finishes, how do I know that thread 1 is usable again? Do posix threads have native support for this?

Comment: Presumably, thread-start command would take a function pointer or something like that, for the thread to run. The thread is usable again when that function returns.

Comment: Are you talking about "posix threads", or `std::thread`s? The basic answer is logically the same, in either case, except that if this is posix threads, this is not a C++ issue; and if this is `std::thread`, then you need to clarify it accordingly. `std::thread`s are not posix threads, technically, and can use any logically-comparable implementation.

Comment: I'm using pthread.h

Comment: I'm outsourcing all the work of the threading to the c++ file, but I don' have any way of knowing when the function returns. I'm more curious if posix threads have some built in function, that takes as a parameter a thread, and returns whether that thread is currently in use